# What kind of bibliography style should I use for this

Tags: bibtex

What kind of style should I choose?

Neves VCM, Babb R, Chandrasekaran D, Sharpe PT. Promotion of natural
tooth repair by small molecule GSK3 antagonists. Sci. Rep. 2017; 7: 39654.

Comment: Probably author-title, but this is the wrong place to ask. Try academia.se

Comment: The question as it stands is a bit broad. Are you looking for a specific `bst` style that matches what you want?